# Why is my jquery loader not working?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to add a loading gif to some jquery script. I thought I might use [this plugin](http://www.jqueryscript.net/loading/Minimal-AJAX-Loading-Spinner-Plugin-with-jQuery-pleaseWait.html) which has worked before but I am trying to figure out why it is not firing when I submit a form. Have I got it in the correct place?

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#post_data').submit(function() {
//I've placed the plugin here
            $('#spinner').pleaseWait();
            $.ajax({
                url: 'process.php',
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'html',
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                success: function(newContent) {
                    $('#mytable').prepend('<tr>' + newContent + '</tr>');
                    $("form").trigger("reset");

                }
            });

            return false;
        });
    });
```

The div where I want it to appear.

```
<div class="center-block" id="spinner"></div>
```

Comment: Do you get any errors in the console? Is the plugin loaded correctly? Do you have a valid form called "post_data"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did a fiddle for you: https://jsfiddle.net/2Lazd0ez/

Inserted this line:

```
$('#post_data').submit(function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
});
```

The reason being not using preventDefault() and actually submitting the form serverside, instead of through jQuery.

Answer (score 2):

Reasons :

Give some width height to spinner div.
Try customize the spinner as given in the plug-in.
Load scripts at end of body both jQuery after that loader plug-in.
Just try with only spinner plug-in without ajax.
Add beforesend property in ajax and in that method load the spinner and stop at ajax complete property